# JButton move text

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm searching for a solution/alternative for my JButton Problem. My buttontext isn't matching correctly with my "keyboard key picture". The text is a little too low..

```
JToggleButton tglbtn_newLine = new JToggleButton("0");
tglbtn_newLine.setBackground(new Color(240,240,240));
tglbtn_newLine.setBorderPainted(false);
tglbtn_newLine.setIcon(new ImageIcon(/*Picture of a key*/);
//should be 2..3 pix above the CENTER position:
tglbtn_newLine.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
tglbtn_newLine.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
GridBagConstraints gbc_tglbtn_newLine = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_tglbtn_newLine.insets = new Insets( 0, 0, 5, 5);
tglbtn_newLine.setMargin(new Insets(-2, -2, -2, -2));
gbc_tglbtn_newLine.gridx = 4;
gbc_tglbtn_newLine.gridy = 5;
controlPanel.add(tglbtn_newLine, gbc_tglbtn_newLine);
```

Is there a possibility to set the text to a specific y-position.

Example pic:

[image: Example]

Comment: I don't see the problem. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tried and tried... nothing seems to work.

I solved it now, that I resized the picture about 5 pixels. So the `CENTER` will be higher.
Finally `setMargin(new Insets(-8, -2, -2, -2));` an now it should work with dynamic text.
It's not perfect but it works :/

Thx for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You might get some ideas from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151403) that uses `setBorderPainted(false)` and `paintComponent()` to precisely control placement and scale.