# Java replace JFrame with JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to 'embed' an existing Java app into my own application.
The existing app is a `JFrame` with a number of components added to it. I copied the code into my project and replaced the `JFrame` with a new `JPanel` that I then added to my own app.

The problem is everything painted in the `JPanel` appears to be shifted up by a small amount (e.g. ~20px). I wondered if it's anything to do with window menubars etc but so far haven't been able to find a solution apart from manually adding an offset when painting (definitely not ideal!).

I know without the code it can be difficult to offer helpful suggestions, but what I want to know is, do the `JFrame` and `JPanel` behave differently in a way that would cause this? Or is there anything else obvious to fix it?

Comment: I have a pony, guess what color it is - Without some kind of runnable example which demonstrates your problem, we'd only be guessing at what color your pony is, which isn't going to help anybody :( - And no, there's nothing "obvious" which would cause this

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's an unfair question. The pony is a Unicorn and it's rainbow colored.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Damn, you know me to well 

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to **create an empty border.** Try something like this:

```
panelName.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 0, 0, 0));
```

This will shift everything in the `JPanel` down 20 pixels, and it should solve your problem. Try adjusting the number of pixels until you find the center.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115065/jlabel-vertical-alignment-not-working-as-expected).

Comment: *"This is a problem which JPanels have"* - Since when? I've never had a panel offset itself without me doing something to warrant it.  So, instead of actually fixing the issue, you're just suggesting to apply a "hack" to correct for whatever the real, underlying issue is? Talk about using a bandaid to cover a hemorrhage

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have come across this problem many times, and this fixed my problem. It's only a cut. Perfect for a band-aid.

Comment: If you've come "across this issue many times" then you're doing something wrong

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not doing anything "wrong." There's nothing harmful about it. It just happens when you set the label too small to fit the text or image normally

Comment: NEVER had this kind of issue - and there are a lot of assumptions associated with the question

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have edited my answer. There is NOTHING false about it, and it will solve the OP's problem.

Comment: It's still hack around the base problem, if the linked answer is a hack