# Why doesn't my JFrame show up?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to make a solved sudoku puzzle show up in a window with 81 boxes. I did this:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class GraphicSolver extends JFrame {

GraphicSolver(int[][] spelplan) {

    Panel panel = new Panel(new GridLayout(9,9));

    for(int i=9;i<9;i++){
        for(int x=0;x<9;x++){
            panel.add(new JLabel(""+spelplan[i][x]));
        }
    }

    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.add(panel);


    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

However, it only gives me an empty window without any numbers. I'd be pleased if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you also post the code that initiates and display the JFrame (your main method or something like that)

Comment: Don't mix Swing & AWT components!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The outer loop should start at zero:

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
```

Comment: Oh, simple stupid mistake, thanks for pointing it out! I accept this as the answer, as it was the main thing that broke the program.

Comment: Glad to help; also consider up-voting related answers you found helpful.

Comment: See also [`CellTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148336/jformattedtextfield-is-not-properly-cleared/4151403#4151403).

Answer (score 4):

Try calling `frame.pack ()`, this will pack all the components into the frame to be displayed after computing the correct size with the panels. Also, follow the fix suggested by @trashgod above will solve the fact that no panels were added, and the fix by @Ashkan Aryan will make your code a bit more reasonable (although it should work without it, but then there is no point in inheriting from JFrame).

The code below works for me:

```
GraphicSolver(int[][] spelplan) {
    Panel panel = new Panel(new GridLayout(9,9));

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        for(int x=0;x<9;x++){
            panel.add(new JLabel(""+spelplan[i][x]));
        }
    }

    this.add(panel);
    this.pack ();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have two Frames. 1 is the JFrame (the class GrpahicSolver itself) and the other a frame that you are creating within it.

I suggest you replace frame.addPanel() with this.addPanel() and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Graphic Solver]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphicSolver {

    GraphicSolver(int[][] spelplan) {
        // presumes each array 'row' is the same length
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(
            spelplan.length,
            spelplan[0].length,
            8,
            4));

        for(int i=0;i<spelplan.length;i++){
            for(int x=0;x<spelplan[i].length;x++){
                panel.add(new JLabel(""+spelplan[i][x]));
            }
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int[][] plan = new int[4][7];
                for (int x=0; x<plan.length; x++) {
                    for (int y=0; y<plan[x].length; y++) {
                        plan[x][y] = (x*10)+y;
                    }
                }
                new GraphicSolver(plan);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for spacing; a matching empty border on the panel complements the effect.

Comment: @trashgod I was going to add a border, but that was 2 whole more lines of code, & I decided to stop there.