# Always display text inside JButton no matter it's size

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, font-size

In java, I want to set a JButton font size so that it will not display '...' (ellipsis). The text of the JButton will only ever be one character, but I want to resize the window and have the layout manager resize the font so that it won't show ... How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

[`CellTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148336/jformattedtextfield-is-not-properly-cleared/4151403#4151403) shows one approach that renders the digit at a suitably large size (128 pixels) and scales the image as required.