# Unable to introduce Text in next line when using Header Checkbox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I'm definitely not the best at explaining problem but let me try.

I have an applet with me. In a `JTabel` I have one column as checkbox.

I want to have text added to it in the header only such that I have some text and than in the next line I have the checkbox.

Using `headerRenderer` setText is not helping my cause as it appends the test to the checkbox instead of introducing a new line. Moreover I would like to avoid using `JPanel` because I think it will create lot more problems for me.

Can anyone suggest how I can get this done?

If `JPanel` is the only option can someone tell me how do I use that.

Comment: edit youd question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), demonstraded your issue with JCheckBox in the TableHeader

Answer (score 0):

The Q&A [*How can I put a control in the `JTableHeader` of a `JTable`?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7137786/230513) includes several important caveats and shows an example using `JToggleButton`. In this case you want a two line  `JCheckBox` without the complication of an enclosing `JPanel`.

You might look at implementing the `Icon` interface, as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834484/230513) for a `TableCellRenderer`. This would allow you to leverage the control offered by the component's horizontal and vertical alignment. For consistency, use the UI properties of the `JCheckBox` for the text, as shown in [`SelectAllHeader`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513). I'd try rendering a `JLabel` in `paintIcon ()`, but `TextLayout`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8282330/230513), is an alternative way to get the correct metrics.