# How to edit a text that is converted into image? or any other approach to realize/edit text

Tags: java, swing, text, awt, jtextpane

For my project I want to resize text just like in Adobe Photoshop. But when I tried resizing(by mouse drag) the textpane, only the textpane was getting resized and not the text inside it. Then I tried converting my text to image and tried resizing  it again (As mentioned in the post [How to resize text in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440201/how-to-resize-text-in-java)) and it worked fine.. Now I have another problem of editing my text. i.e. once my text is converted to image then how do i edit it (eg: changing the text color, etc).

Any idea on this?

Comment: The example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13441449/230513) calls `createImage()` whenever `setText()` gets called.

Comment: this site is giving me some error while posting the code!! But please refer this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281886/stretch-a-jlabel-text/8282330#8282330). Here they are doing the same thing. They have stretched the text "Sample" by converting it to image. Now can you tell me how do i edit that text (i.e. lets say I want to change the color of Sample after it is converted to image).

Comment: Andrew could you please more elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

> ..once my text is converted to image then how do I edit it (eg: changing the text color, etc).

Don't. It is better (quality) and easier to paint the image each choice with the text when requested, in the desired `Font`, starting `Point`, `AffineTransform`, `RenderinhHints` and `Color` (etc.).

[image: StretchLabels]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.*;

public class StretchLabels {

    String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!";
    Font font = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 24);

    public JComponent getGUI() {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel l1 = new StretchTextLabel(s);
        l1.setFont(font);
        gui.add(l1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return gui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Streeetch me!");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                StretchLabels eg = new StretchLabels();
                f.setContentPane(eg.getGUI());
                f.pack();

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class StretchTextLabel extends JLabel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public StretchTextLabel(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
        Color c = gr.getColor();
        setForeground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        setForeground(c);
        gr.setColor(c);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr; 
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        double pw = this.getPreferredSize().width;
        double ph = this.getPreferredSize().height;
        double w = this.getSize().width;
        double h = this.getSize().height;

        // Set FG (text) color
        g.setColor(this.getForeground());

        // stretch
        AffineTransform stretch =
                AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(w/pw, h/ph);
        g.setTransform(stretch);
        g.drawString(getText(), 0, this.getFont().getSize());
    }
}
```

> .. how do I edit the text in the image?

I typically offer controls to do it like this:

[image: Text Control]

But of course, that does not cover:

1. Color, which has a control in the main GUI (a basic paint app.)
   [image: Basic paint app.]
2. Scaling of the resulting text by 'drag'.  Which might be achieved by using a resizable element as demonstrated by either @trashgod or myself (above).

Comment: Hi Andrew, the above code will convert text to image but after the conversion how do I edit the text in the image?

Comment: *"..edit the text in the image?"*  Set the text of the label.  You might have a statically sized text field above it (or as a pop-up) to edit the text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the text to image, why don't you increase the text's size so it grows along with the pane?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I can't find how to do it. I think I don't have enough priviledge to write comments to other people's messages...

Comment: Yes I could do that. But I have a very rare requirement of increasing only the width of text and not height. So I thought Stretching would be a good option

Comment: Well, I don't know if I'm being naive, but in that case I guess you could store the original text and perform the "text to image" conversion everytime you change styling properties.