# How to adjust font size on image resize?

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to edit a text that is converted into image? or any other approach to realize/edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485501/how-to-edit-a-text-that-is-converted-into-image-or-any-other-approach-to-realiz)

What I am trying to achieve is that... I have a text in textpane which I am converting to BufferedImage and resizing the size of the image by dragging it with mouse. Now If I want to edit the text, I am clicking on the image which hides the image and shows the text from textpane.

My problem is the size of the text in textpane is not resized(increased/decreased) as resize was done on image and not on text. So how do I change the font size as and when I resize the image containg text?

Comment: can u post your piece of code

Comment: You don't seem to be learning anything from your earlier threads.  :(

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the font size by deriving the base font with a `AffineTransform`.  Basically, you will need to maintain a reference to the base font that the user started with.  When you need to, you would derive a new font instance by suppling a `AffineTransform` with the appropriate scale and apply that to the text pane

See [`Font#deriveFont(AffineTransform trans)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28java.awt.geom.AffineTransform%29) for more details

Comment: +1 ive been thinking about the answer to this for some time.. great stuff :)

Comment: +1 for using `AffineTransform` directly with `Font`.  I did not think of that the other day when [mentioning transforms to this questioner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13440543/418556).

Comment: I was going to mention the UITransform from JXLayer, but I don't have an example to show :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to scale the `JTextPane`'s content as described here http://java-sl.com/Scale_In_JEditorPane.html

Just listen resize and adapt the scale factor acordingly