# Scrolls not appears

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I want add JScrolpane to JPanel, but that not appears. In JLabel works fine and its very easy. I am using JPanel beacuse I'll add some image proccessing stuff to my program. There is my code:

```
public void draw(){  
 panel=new JPanel(){
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            Graphics g2 = g.create();
            g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            g2.dispose();             
        }         
 };   
 panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
 panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 330));
 s=new JScrollPane(panel);
 s.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,285));
 this.getContentPane().add(s,BorderLayout.CENTER);
 add(panel);
 revalidate();  
 repaint();     
 }
```

Comment: It would help if you posted a sscce http://sscce.org

Comment: As long as we are giving free advice ;-): Don't call `setPreferredSize()`. Either override `getPreferredSize()` or use an appropriate `LayoutManagerµ .

Comment: @Guillaume Polet You have right partly. See my answer.

Comment: @Michal in your case, you should obviously override `getPreferredSize()` and return the size of the image you paint. If at some point you were to switch to another image with a different size, all you would need to call is `revalidate(); repaint();` and it would all work perfectly.

Comment: Hmm this trick with s.getPrefferedSize(); not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! The main reason for me was no-layout manager and no-declarated size of this. There is my code:

```
public void draw(){
 panel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout()){
 @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        }         
 };   
 panel.setBounds(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
 panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(),obraz.getHeight()));
 JScrollPane scrolls=new JScrollPane(panel,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

 add(scrolls);
 validate();  
 repaint();     
 }
```

But if someone will want copy this code in the future, there is one thing to be known- a size of Jpanel isn't refreshing (it's always one size of first opened image), but I have scrolsl and I am satisfied for now ;). Thanks a lot for everyone.

Comment: Consider calling `revalidate()` rather than `validate()`

Answer (score 3):

```
 s=new JScrollPane(panel);
 s.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,285));
 this.getContentPane().add(s,BorderLayout.CENTER);
 add(panel); // ****** ????????????
 revalidate();  
 repaint();     
}
```

You're adding the JPanel to the GUI not the JScrollPane, so you really shouldn't expect to see any scrollpanes if they've not been added anywhere.

Solution: Add your JScrollPane, s, that holds the JPanel to the GUI, not JPanel itself.

Answer (score 3):

You dont honor the *paint chain*, call `super.paintComponent(g)` as first call in overridden `paintComponent` method. i.e

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
      super.paintComponent(g); 
      //draw here
}
```

or visual artifacts may occur.

- Also note the `@Override` annotation which should be used with overridden methods in order to gain the advantage of compiler checking that we overrode the method correctly.
- There is no need for `getContentPane().add(..)` simply call add on `JFrame` instance as `add(..)` along with `remove(..)` and `setLayout(..)` have been forward to the `JFrame`s *contentPane*
- Also not a good idea to go extending `JFrame` for nor reason, simply create an instance and use that i.e:

  ```
  JFrame frame=new JFrame("Title here");
  ...
  frame.add(..);
  ...
  frame.pack();
  frame.visible(true);
  ```
- Also draw onto the `Graphics` object passed into paintComponent `g` dont go creating your own in `paintComponent`. Unless of course you're doing if for the reason @HFOE mentioned in below comment :).
- No need for `this` parameter in `drawImage(..)` unless your `JPanel` implements on `ImageObserver` or the image may not be fully loaded when painting occurs. Simply use `null`.
- And just for the cherry on top use some [`Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) and [`RenderHints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html) as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323068/java-how-to-add-string-below-an-image-and-resizing-it/14323395#14323395). This will allow for a better quality image to be drawn and text.

Comment: It's OK to create a new Graphics object if there's a risk that you may make changes to it that you don't want propagated elsewhere in your GUI such as in your JPanel's children. By changes I mean things such as setting an AffineTransform or Stroke. Otherwise 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels +1 good point updated answer accorodingly