# Cannot put image in Frame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, overriding

I am a beginner programmer trying to create a Pacman game using Java eclipse. I am at the beginning of the process and I'm simply trying to get my main `"Princess Pacman"` character on the `JFrame` screen, but, I have this Override error popping up. I have also tried it with out override but it doesn't seem to be working for me that way either.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Pacman extends JFrame {
    public static final int WIDTH = 500;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 500;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Pacman gui = new Pacman();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

    BufferedImage princess = null;
    public Pacman(){
        super("Princess Pacman");
        //set size of playing space
        setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        try{
             princess =ImageIO.read(new File("images/Elsa.jpeg"));
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("image not found");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g){
        g.drawImage(princess.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT), 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `draw` is not a method defined by `JFrame` or any of its parent classes, therefore it can't be override
- `draw` is never called by anything that actually paints
- You should avoid painting directly to top level containers, there's just to many things been painted onto it.
- You can use a `JLabel`, but there are issues with this. Instead, create a custom class extending from `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method, making sure you call `super.paintComponent` before you render the image

Take a closer look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393971/having-images-as-background-of-jpanel/18394047#18394047)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to override a method that does not exist in the JFrame class. Remove the override annotation.

Comment: Oh, good to know. Thank you. However, this does not fix my problem that the image is not showing up on the JFrame. Any suggestions?