# How to force overlap of JLabels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, flowlayout

I know I still need to convert string to int and to double for providerID and providerPrice so I can set them and then store them later; I expect I can figure that out just fine.  What I can't seem to find is how to make the JLabels align properly.  The cloudBack label should be the main background, and each set of JLabel and JTextField should be on a separate line overlapping the main background, with the 3 JButtons on bottom.  How do I make them go in the right places?  btw the source .png is 400x224 pixels
        package newprovider;

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

/*@Michael Christopher,  author/owner */
public class NewProvider {
/** @param args the command line arguments*/
public static void createGUI() {
    // Create the window
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame ("NewProvider");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create the MenuBar
    JMenuBar maintenanceMenuBar = new JMenuBar ();
    maintenanceMenuBar.setOpaque(true);
    maintenanceMenuBar.setBackground(new Color(176,224,230));
    maintenanceMenuBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 20));

    //create variables
    int providerID;
    String providerName;
    Double providerPrice;
    int addProviderCheck;
    String[] options = {"Yes","No"};

    //create image icon, labels, and JTextFields
    JLabel cloudBack;
    cloudBack = new JLabel (new ImageIcon("images/CloudBack.png"));
    JLabel labelID = new JLabel ("New ProviderID");
    JTextField textID = new JTextField("providerID \n", 10);
    JLabel labelName = new JLabel ("New Provider Name");
    JTextField textName = new JTextField("Provider Name \n", 20);
    JLabel labelPrice = new JLabel ("New Provider Price");
    JTextField textPrice = new JTextField ("Price \n", 5);
    //make Submit, Clear, & Exit buttons
    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");   
    JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");

    /*Set the FlowLayout to arrange the window, setting labels, text fields,
    menubar, background, and orientation*/
    FlowLayout newProviderLayout = new FlowLayout();
    mainFrame.setLayout(newProviderLayout);
    mainFrame.setJMenuBar(maintenanceMenuBar);
    mainFrame.add(cloudBack, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainFrame.add(labelID);
    mainFrame.add(textID);
    mainFrame.add(labelName);
    mainFrame.add(textName);
    mainFrame.add(labelPrice);
    mainFrame.add(textPrice);
    mainFrame.add(submit);
    mainFrame.add(clear);
    mainFrame.add(exit);

    //ActionListener for Submit button
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String ID = textID.getText();
                    String Name = textName.getText();
                    String Price = textPrice.getText();
            int submitPress = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
     "ProviderID: " + ID + "\n" + "Provider Name: " + Name +"\n" + "Provider Price: " + Price,
     "Please Verify Content",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,null, options,options[0]); 
if (submitPress <= 0) {                  
    //Store Displayed data
    System.out.println(ID);
    System.out.println(Name);
    System.out.println(Price);
    /*providerID = ID;
    providerName = Name;
    providerPrice = Price;  */
    textID.setText("Confirmed");
}
else if (submitPress > 0) {      
            textID.setText("providerID");
            textName.setText("Provider Name");
            textPrice.setText("Price"); }
        }
    });
    //ActionListener for clear button
    clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textID.setText("providerID");
            textName.setText("Provider Name");
            textPrice.setText("Price"); }
    });
    //ActionListener for Exit Button
    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {   @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mainFrame.setVisible(false);
            mainFrame.dispose(); }
    });
//verify intent to add new provider to system before continuing
addProviderCheck = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
     "This will add a new service provider to the database.\n" 
    + "Are you sure you wish to continue?",
     "Please Verify Intent",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, options,options[0]); 
if (addProviderCheck <= 0) {
              //Display Window
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);}
else { //else close app
    mainFrame.setVisible(false);
    mainFrame.dispose();
}
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    //draw and show the GUI
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        createGUI();
    });        
    //store new provider data
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you've posted non-compilable code. Please fix this.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176008/background-image-for-a-jpanel-not-working/24176183#24176183), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162398/how-to-set-a-background-picture-in-jpanel/22162430#22162430), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393971/having-images-as-background-of-jpanel/18394047#18394047)

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - package newprovider; was supposed to be in the code block as the top line; aside from that, it's a copy>paste of my working code - is that all you meant or is there a bigger problem I'm missing?  MadProgrammer - looking over your examples, ty.  Hovercraft 's second answer - thank you.  I'm going to spend today looking at JPanel and paintComponent, plus the other 2 layouts you referenced.

Comment: Apparently I was wrong about being able to figure out the int and double.  I can parse them to new variables, but I can't get them to set to the input values.  Netbeans keeps telling me that "Local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final."  If I set the 3 variables to final up where they are defined, netbeans then tells me to remove final, then restarts the cycle.

Comment: in the if block for the submit button:    int pID = Integer.parseInt(ID);
                    double dPrice = Double.parseDouble(Price);
                    providerID = pID;
                    providerName = Name;
                    providerPrice = dPrice;

Comment: Make the key variables non-final instance fields in the class, not local variables, and this will rid you of the final-non-final issue. This is what I was referring to above when I mentioned that your code was non-compilable, this and the other un-posted classes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of displayiing your CloudBack.jpg in a JLabel, consider drawing it in a JPanel's paintComponent method using `g.drawImage(...)`, and then placing your other components onto this drawing JPanel. Note that if you add any other JPanels onto the drawing JPanel, be sure that the non-drawing JPanels are set to be non-opaque via `setOpaque(false)`.

I also suggest that you don't use FlowLayout as your main GUI layout since it is not going to add your components in a pleasing, easy to use and view way. Consider looking into use of GridBagLayout or MigLayout in addition to BorderLayout.

Comment: I've fixed everything functionally, though I haven't gotten to the layout change yet - I have to look up JPanels tomorrow.  Aside from that, any problems in the new code that would be created by implementing a JPanel with drawImage and GridBagLayout? (I did look that part up lol) - edit - I can't post the new code because its too long for a comment... suggestions?