# Put text on animated GIF and save it as a new GIF

Tags: java, image, image-processing, gif, javax.imageio

I'm looking for a function that could process animated gif image to write text on top of it.

The working solution is probably provided by Gif4j lib, but I'm looking for open-source solution or advice how to implement it on my own.

How can I put text on a gif and save it as a new gif in Java?

Comment: `Graphics.drawString()` but not sure if it would work for an animated image.

Comment: [This](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-programmer/32892/Help-with-GIF-writer-in-imageio#art5) is creating an animated gif using ImageIO. You could just draw the text on the offscreen images before you create the gif

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

1. Split the animation into separate frames.
2. Write the text on each frame.  For examples see answers like these (the first is more closely related, but the second source does the same, and is simpler).

   - [Java Text on Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998015/418556)
   - [How to resize text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13440543/418556) <sup>1</sup>
3. Construct the frames into a new animated GIF. See [Create animated GIF using imageio](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1262385)  at the OTN, where I discuss the code used in a GIF animation tool.

[image]

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize that link was you! Anyways +1!

Comment: Thanks, Andrew this looks promising - i'll try it. Also, do you have any suggestions for the first and second steps?

Comment: For the first, only a very bad one (which is so much of a hack that I dare not even mention it).  For the second, see the edit.