# Rescale Animation

Tags: java, animation, resize, scale, rescale

I have some code that code that's supposed to animate parts of my program, and right now, the animation dimensions are hard coded, i.e. every distance and location is specified by a number. I was just wondering, is there a way to rescale the animation panel, so that the hard-coded thing will work on computers with smaller screens?

Comment: Yes, don't hard code values. Instead use methods like `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` to get the size of the panel. Then base you logic of the actual width/height of the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [scale instance of an `AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getScaleInstance%28double,%20double%29) for this.  Here is [an example of scaling text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13440543/418556).

[image]