# Screenshot capture in Window 8 OS

Tags: java, windows-8, awt

To capture screen shot in my java application i have write following code

```
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);

ImageIO.write(capture, "png", new File("resources/img/screenshot.png"));
```

This is working successfully and capture screen shot but this is not working in windows 8 operating system. any one else who have face this type of problem and get soluction?

Comment: For me it's working perfectly (Windows 8.1 Update 1 64-bit). Though, why are you using format bmp and saving in .png ?

Comment: I have find out the orignel problme. my application is install into the program file folder and the windows 8 not give permission to write there how i can write there now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that without writing file in your local machine by using the following code

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] imageByte = null;
   try
   {
        //To Get the the size of the screen.
        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit
                .getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());          

        //To Store the scrreen shot in buffer.
        BufferedImage capture = new Robot()
                .createScreenCapture(screenRect);   

        //To Save the image on specific location.
        ImageIO.write(capture, "png",bos);
        bos.flush();
        imageByte=bos.toByteArray();
        bos.close();

         // File file = new File("resources/img/screenshot.png");
        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
      //  ContentBody cfBody = new FileBody(file);
          ContentBody cfBody = new ByteArrayBody(imageByte,"screenshot.png");
        mpEntity.addPart("screenshot", cfBody);
```

}

send direct the byte array in plase of the image

Answer (score 1):

> my application is install into the program file folder and the windows 8 not give permission to write there how i can write there now?

Do **not** write it there!  OS manufacturers as well as Sun/Oracle have been saying for years ***not*** to write files to the application's installation directory.  It is not only the wrong place to write them, but as you have discovered, does not provide write permissions for a typical Java app.

Instead put the screen-shot in `user.home` e.g. as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13440543/418556).