# How to add transparent text to photo?

Tags: java, image, swing, text, java-2d

I have got a stupid problem.I want add a text with alpha 0.5 to my photo to make a watermark but `setColor` doesn't add a color. When I trying use `setComposite` I see the error "cannot find symbol".

```
buffered.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            buffered.getGraphics().setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,
             0.1f));
buffered.getGraphics().setColor(new Color(0.2f,0.3f,0.4f,0.5f));
buffered.getGraphics().setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 32));
buffered.getGraphics().drawString("text", img.getWidth()/2, img.getHeight()/2);
buffered.getGraphics().dispose();
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13440543/418556) shows how to use the color to create translucent text. (I'm considering using it to close this as a duplicate - though it's about transforms mostly.)

Comment: *"When I trying use `setComposite` I see the error "cannot find symbol"." .. `buffered.getGraphics()`* This is not entirely relevant to the stated aim, since it's not necessary to use composites in order to get translucent text. Having said that, it is easy to explain.[`setComposite(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setComposite-java.awt.Composite-) is a method of the **`Graphics2D`** API, whereas [`BufferedImage.getGraphics()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getGraphics--) returns a `Graphics` object ..

Comment: .. To gain a `Graphics2D` instance, call [**`createGraphics()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics--)

Comment: Since you seem to have ignored my advice, I'll vote to close and close this question tab in my browser. All the best with it!

Answer (score 0):

Simple: You're calling getGraphics() multiple times. You get a *new* Graphics object on every call.

Call getGraphics() only once and use the reference for all further calls.