# How to measure height of text that is presented by single String and limited by width, so it'd be multiline?

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I am going to draw multiline text. Text is limited by width, it wouldn't fit there, so I'd like to how many lines would be there, i.e. I need height of rectangle. I have font variable in Java. How can I do that?

Comment: are you using monospaced fonts? if so, you can look at your wrapper that how many characters on line 1 appears. then you can split your whole text to that number. this may give you the line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html
it works if you reflect the text in `JEditorPane/JTextPane`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Measuring Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html), in particular [Drawing Multiple Lines of Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/drawmulstring.html)

Comment: There's a related `TextLayout` example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8282330/230513).