# Using an affline transformation to set font size to be proportional to its container in Swing

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt, java-2d

So, slightly different than similar questions on SO but any insight in how I would use an affline transformation to shrink or grow a text string so that the overall size is proportional to the region it's to be drawn on?

For example, I'd like the font to be 50% of the width of the region.

I've inherited some code like this but I don't really understand what its doing

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);
FontRenderContext context = graphics.getFontRenderContext();
graphics.setFont(font);
Rectangle2D bounds = graphics.getFont().getStringBounds("Hello world", context);

LineMetrics line = font.getLineMetrics(text, context);
float xScale = (float) (region.width / bounds.getWidth());
float yScale = (region.height / (line.getAscent() + line.getDescent()));

double x = region.x;
double y = region.y + region.height - (yScale * line.getDescent());
AffineTransform transformation = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);

if (xScale > yScale)
    transformation.scale(yScale, yScale);
else
    transformation.scale(xScale, xScale);

graphics.setFont(font.deriveFont(transformation));
graphics.setRenderingHint(KEY_ANTIALIASING, VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

int centerX = region.width / 2;
int centerY = region.height / 2;
graphics.drawString(text, centerX, centerY - (int) bounds.getHeight());
```

It seems to set the size to something reasonable but not center this in the region. If you can shed light on what its *trying* to do, that'd be great.

Any pointers (as long as they're not literally pointers to the java font tutorial) much appreciated.

Comment: How's that? I'd be happy if could calculate just the font size to use based on its container rather than transform the existing font but I'm not sure how/if a transform reduces the quality...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this "seems" to try to center the text within a "given" area...

```
// Set the base, start font
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);
// Get rendering context
FontRenderContext context = graphics.getFontRenderContext();
// Set the font used by the graphics context...
graphics.setFont(font);
// Get the rectangle "bounds" of the text
Rectangle2D bounds = graphics.getFont().getStringBounds("Hello world", context);
// Get the line metrics, which describes things like the fonts decent and ascent
LineMetrics line = font.getLineMetrics(text, context);
// Calculate the scaling requirements
float xScale = (float) (region.width / bounds.getWidth());
float yScale = (region.height / (line.getAscent() + line.getDescent()));

// Calculate the offset for the text
double x = region.x;
double y = region.y + region.height - (yScale * line.getDescent());
// Create a new transformation, translating the x, y position
// This appears to be trying to place the text at the bottom
// left position of the region, but the problem is, this then gets
// scaled, when means that this translation is no longer the same...   
AffineTransform transformation = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);

// Apply a scale...
if (xScale > yScale)
    transformation.scale(yScale, yScale);
else
    transformation.scale(xScale, xScale);

// Create a new instance of the font using the transformation
graphics.setFont(font.deriveFont(transformation));
// Make it look pretty
graphics.setRenderingHint(KEY_ANTIALIASING, VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

// Render the font within the region...
int centerX = region.width / 2;
int centerY = region.height / 2;
graphics.drawString(text, centerX, centerY - (int) bounds.getHeight());
```

Now, having said all that, I've had a hard time getting it to work.  Because you are simply creating a new `Font` based on the transformation, it would be simpler to throw away the translation, for example...

```
// Base font
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);
// Get the fonts metrics
FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics(font);

// Calculate the scaling requirements
float xScale = (float) (region.width / fm.stringWidth(text));
float yScale = (region.height / fm.getHeight());

// Determine which access to scale on...
float scale = 0f;
if (xScale > yScale) {
    scale = yScale;
} else {
    scale = xScale;
}

// Create a new font using the scaling facter
g2d.setFont(font.deriveFont(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale)));
// Make it pretty
g2d.setRenderingHint(KEY_ANTIALIASING, VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

// Get the "scaled" metrics
fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

// Position the text at the left, bottom position of the
// specified region...
int x = 0;
int y = (region.height - fm.getHeight()) + fm.getAscent();
g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
```

Not sure if that's exactly right (what you're looking for), but that's what the code you supplied "seems" to be trying to do...

Comment: +1 for `FontMetrics`; @Toby: also consider `TextLayout`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8282330/230513).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a combination of this and  http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/drawing-text-about-its-visual-center/