# How can I change the foreground color of a text based on the background it is on?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel

I have a `JCheckbox`,this is in a `JPanel`, that is supposed to show an image in the `JPanel`, when you select it. The problem is this: as you can see in the screenshot, the text of the `JCheckbox` is difficult to read because of the image.

[image: screenshot]

I was thinking if there was some way to contrast the text to the image, so that the color of the text is the opposite of the image.

I know that there're other ways to fix it, like setting the `JCheckbox` outside the image, but I'd have to change design of my program and structure code.

For example, here's how I want it to look:

[image: look].

This is all the code that the `JCheckBox` currently has, it is something simple:

```java
        final JCheckBox INFO_IMG = new JCheckBox("Ver img");

        INFO_IMG.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 0, 12));
        INFO_IMG.setBounds(-2, 2, 78, 13);
        INFO_IMG.setOpaque(false);
        INFO_IMG.setFocusable(false);
        INFO_IMG.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(final ItemEvent ie) {
                if (1 == ie.getStateChange()) {
                    INFO_IMG.setText("Ver info");
                    IMG.setVisible(true);
/*                  INFO_IMG.setForegound(ROBOT.getPixelColor(
                    (int)INFO_IMG.getLocationOnScreen.getX() + 12 
                    ,(int) INFO_IMG.getLocationOnScreen().getY() + 10)); 

                   This is another way that I had thought of,
                   although it does not work well,would also have to get 
                   the opposite color from the one return.
*/
              } else { 
                    INFO_IMG.setText("Ver img");
                    IMG.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
        add(INFO_IMG);
```

Comment: Have you tried the `UIManager` property [`"CheckBox.foreground"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswing%5D+%22CheckBox.foreground%22)? If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: Alternatively, XOR the text on the image and `setText("")`.

Comment: Hello, I did not know that property, could you explain in more detail, please, and thank you.
oh sorry now I add more info.

Comment: I certainly hadn't thought of that alternative, I'll use it as a last resort

Comment: Here are more examples using [`UIManager.put`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswing%5d%20UIManager.put).

Comment: I'm confused.  For a `JCheckBox`, you can set the foreground and background colors so they contrast.  If you want something like the white/black image you posted, you'll have to create a BufferedImage and set the image to the `JCheckBox`.

Comment: What do not you understand? Sorry if it is not well explained, I will make some corrections, I think that doing what you say is somewhat complicated for what I want, anyway where can I see more information about that. No, not only black / white, it can any other color, it depends on the color of the image, the image can be chosen by the user.

Comment: I share @GilbertLeBlanc's doubts. I sense that you don't want the white/black image; I'm guessing that you want to ensure that the text is legible over _any_ background. With some adjustment, I'd recommend this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513). I urge you to continue experimenting. In your revised [mre], access posted images via `URL`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513); use synthetic images as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15982915/230513); or use `UIManager` icons, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).

Comment: To enhance contrast, first paint a neutral background for the text; you can get its boundary  like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8282330/230513).

Comment: trashgod, If I thought about it, if I can not otherwise, I will surely do it like this. Thanks for your answer. Now I will try what was recommended to me, then I will comment on how it worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found this way to do it, but unfortunately it only works for black and white, can you think of other ways?

```java
Public Color contrast(Image image) {
    BufferedImage buffered = toBufferedImage(image);
        
    int black = 0, white = 0;
        
    for (int x = 0; x < buffered.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < buffered.getHeight(); y++) {
            if(buffered.getRGB(x, y) == Color.BLACK.getRGB()) {
                black++;
            }else {
                white++;
            }
        }
    }
        
    System.out.println("Blanco: " + white + ", Negro: " + black);
    
    return (white > black) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE;
}

private BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image image) {
    int width = image.getWidth(null);
    int height = image.getHeight(null);
    int argb = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY;
        
    BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(width, height, argb);
        
    Graphics2D g2 = buffered.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2.dispose(); 
        
    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ImageIcon(buffered));

    return buffered;
}
```