# Sudoku GUI using java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, sudoku, solver

I'm currently working on my GUI for this Sudoku solver I'm making. I've managed to print out the board with no problems. However I'd like to know how I would go about to differentiate the 3x3 regions with some kind of thicker or coloured line.

Basically something resembling the picture below.

[image: sudoku]

Below is the code I've already implemented. Thanks!

```
    Board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9, 9));
    for(int i= 0; i < 9; i++) {

        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {

            board[i][j] = new JLabel();

            board[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));


            Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20);

            board[i][j].setFont(font);

            board[i][j].setForeground(Color.WHITE);

            board[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);


            board[i][j].setOpaque(true);

            board[i][j].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

            Board.add(board[i][j]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: See also [`CellTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4151403/230513).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By far the easiest way would be to use nine 3x3 `JPanel`s of `JLabel`s nested into one large 3x3 `JPanel` of `JPanel`s. Then you could just apply special borders to the small 3x3s.

Comment: Still don't understand how I can do this. I've looked online and all I can find is command prompt boards. They seem to be using modulo 3 statements to make them stand out more. Isn't there a similar way for JLabels that would be easier and shorter to do?

Answer (score 4):

What if you created your own custom JPanel to hold a digit and draw a black border - and then a custom JPanel to hold a grid of those?

Example custom JPanel:

```
    class SudokuPanel extends JPanel {

        int digit; //the number it would display
        int x, y; //the x,y position on the grid

        SudokuPanel(int x, int y) {
            super();

            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            /** create a black border */
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

            /** set size to 50x50 pixel for one square */
            setPreferredSize(50,50);
        }

        public int getDigit() { return digit; }

        //getters for x and y

        public void setDigit(int num) { digit = num }

    }
```

Example custom grid JPanel:

```
    class SudokuGrid extends JPanel {

        SudokuGrid(int w, int h) {
            super(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            /** construct the grid */
            for (int i=0; i<w; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<h; j++) {
                    c.weightx = 1.0;
                    c.weighty = 1.0;
                    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                    c.gridx = i;
                    c.gridy = j;
                    add(new SudokuPanel(i, j), c);
                }
            }

            /** create a black border */ 
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black)); 

        }

    }
```

Example code:

```
...
SudokuGrid sg = new SudokuGrid(3,3);
myFrame.add(sg);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code from Yahoo Answers! on how one would add a JPanel to a JPanel

```
    import javax.swing.*;

public class RecursiveJPanelTest
{
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
JFrame window = new JFrame();
JPanel top = new JPanel();
JPanel within = new JPanel();

window. setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

window.setSize(400, 200);
top.setSize(400, 200);
within.setSize(400, 200);

window.add(top);
top.add(within);
within.add(new JButton("Button"));

window.validate();
window.setVisible(true);
top.setVisible(true);
within.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Couldn't post this in a comment without having it all messed up.