# How to change gap in swing label

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I create some label:

```
leftLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
leftLabel.setFont(new Font(FONT, Font.PLAIN, 280));
leftLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("aaa"));
leftLabel.setText("0");
```

which look like this: [image]

As you can see there are big gap up and down. How I can reduce it ?

Comment: What when you don't pick a font size I can read from a mile off?

Comment: sorry randy but method setAlignmentY() doesn exist

Comment: I try:         leftLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        leftLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
        leftLabel.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        leftLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(-3 /*top*/, 0, 0, 0));
 but still with no success

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to tweak the border insets,

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public final class TitledBorderDemo {
    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(new TitledLabel(String.valueOf(0)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class TitledLabel extends JLabel{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final String TITLE = "aaa";

        TitledLabel(String text){
            super(text);
            setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 280));
            setBorder(new TitledBorder(TITLE){
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets){
                    // arbitrary insets for top and bottom.
                    return new Insets(insets.top - 45, insets.left, insets.bottom - 55, insets.right);
            }});

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();             
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction!

Comment: wow nice example. This works like a charm now I need to create just empty border

Comment: leftLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(-45, 0, -45, 0)));
thx

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/). See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4151403/230513).

Answer (score 2):

the problem is probably within the properties of the newly created border. These borders have insets. That is the only thing I can think of to influence the gaps. Try to call a method on the border that changes these insets to `[1,1,1,1]`.

Comment: the problem isnt in border I add border to show gap in JLabel

Comment: @hudi I'll look deeper into my crystal ball next time.