# Monospace and UTF8

Tags: java, swing, utf-8, monospace

I am correcting Font display in one of our old java Swing application.
Which changed after using  "*-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8*" option at run time.

FontClass.jar is my sample jar file.

```
option 1:
javaw -Xmx256M -jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 "FontClass.jar"

option 2:
javaw -Xmx256M -jar "FontClass.jar"
```

***With option 1:**        I get Monospaced display*

***With option 2:**        I get non Monospaced display.*

**Limitation:**

**i)**  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 This option we have added to have all our streams to support UTF-8 support.
    Insteading of modifing each streams manually.

**ii)** We are using java swing frame work and in many placeses. We are uisng default Font.
    Changing all this is lot of work.

**So now my question is there is any command line option by using which I can get Monospace display with option 1:**

Below is the sample code:

```
class Show extends Frame {
    FontMetrics fontM;
    String outString;

    Show(String target, String title, Font font) {

        setTitle(title);
        outString = target;

        fontM = getFontMetrics(font);
        setFont(font);

        int size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < outString.length(); i++) {
            size += fontM.charWidth(outString.charAt(i));
        }
        size += 24;

        setSize(size, fontM.getHeight() + 60);
        setLocation(getSize().width / 2, getSize().height / 2);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Insets insets = getInsets();
        int x = insets.left;
        int y = insets.top;
        g.drawString(outString, x + 6, y + fontM.getAscent() + 14);
    }
}

public class Fontclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 



        String jaString = new String("\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e\u6587\u5b57\u5217");  

        String inputString = "\niiii\naaaaiiii";

        String displayString = jaString + " " + inputString;

        Font font;
        font = new Font("Courier",3, 24);

        new Show(displayString, "Demo",font);

    }
}
```

Comment: *"Below is the sample code:"*  Where is the question?  Why does the code use AWT components rather than Swing?  Please fix the code formatting, with almost 700 rep. you should have figured it out by now..

Comment: It looks exactly the same for me in both cases...

Comment: For me and many other in my team both looks different. With option 1 Font "Courier" is "Courier". But with option 2 Courier" looks like "Courier new"

Comment: Would it not be reasonable that some text file, say in ISO-8859-1 is involved, maybe listing fonts? Look at fontconfig and psfont*.properties in jre/lib. Maybe a non-ASCII char got inserted.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`FontMetrics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) API, which defines *advance* in terms of `charWidth()`, "Note that the advance of a `String` is not necessarily the sum of the advances of its characters." Moreover, a font named `"Courier"` may be monospaced, but it may *not* be the same font specified by `Font.MONOSPACED`.

Instead, use `TextLayout` to derive the required geometry, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014525/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8282330/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998117/230513).