# How to get text advance (stringWidth) without a Graphics in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt, fontmetrics

How to get text advance (stringWidth) without a `Graphics` instance in Java?

In the [doc examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html), `stringWidth()` is taken from `FontMetrics`, while `FontMetrics` is taken from `Graphics`.

Is it possible to obtain the same without a `Graphics`?

In the notes below it is said, that `Graphics` is required because it holds `FontRenderContext`. But I have `FontRenderContext`, just have no `Graphics`.

So, suppose I have `FontRenderContext` without a `Graphics`. How do I get `stringWidth()` then?

Comment: Why do you "have FontRenderContext without a Graphics"? This sounds weird. Can you post your code?

Comment: Essentially, you can't.  By necessity, you need a `Graphics` context as it defines the properties to which the font will be rendered and will effect how the calculations are made

Comment: @Tunaki I have created frc with `new FontRenderContext(null, isAntiAliased, usesFractionalMetrics)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While "A [`FontRenderContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/FontRenderContext.html) which is directly constructed will most likely not represent any actual graphics device, and may lead to unexpected or incorrect results," you can obtain useful metrics from an instance of [`TextLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014525/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998117/230513).

```
FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, false, false);
TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(text, font, frc);
System.out.println(layout.getBounds());
```

[image]