# How to change diagram Scale in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

[image]

I have a diagram in which x axis shows the time and the y axis shows my data.
I want to change the Scale by choosing different metrics for x axis. e.g second, minute and hour scale. the default is second. therefore if I choose the minute the diagram should be smaller and be more curved. Any idea? The UI is not completed however you suppose that the there would be x and y axis. The parameter degree determines that It should be scaled to second(degree=1),
minute (degree=60) or hour(degree=3600)

```
private void drawLines(Graphics g, ArrayList<Point> points,int degree) throws Exception {

    if (points == null || points.isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception("No points found!!!");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++) {

        Point firstPoint = points.get(i);
        Point secondPoint = points.get(i + 1);

        g.drawLine((int) firstPoint.getX(), (int) firstPoint.getY(), (int) secondPoint.getX(),
                (int) secondPoint.getY());
    }

}
```

Comment: where is the code? what kind of diagram is it? jfreechart?

Comment: No it is not jfreechart. I added the code

Comment: You have a number of choices, you can scale the points in the data or you can scale the `Graphics` context. The first will require you to normalise the data (between 1-0) so you have a point of reference to scale from

Comment: @MadProgrammer: For reference, [tag:jfreechart] scales in the view.

Comment: @trashgod Not all of us are allowed to use third party libraries ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart), which scales the graph to fill the enclosing container. In the example seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513), the enclosing container is a `ChartPanel` that is added to the `CENTER` of frame's default `BorderLayout`. This will allow the graph to grow and shrink as the enclosing frame is resized.

[image]

The general scheme maps model and view coordinates using [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation). Given the following proportions, you can cross-multiply and solve for the missing coordinate, as shown in this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901472/230513) that maps mouse coordinates to pixel coordinates in an image.

```
view.x : panelWidthInPixels :: model.x : modelXRange
view.y : panelHeightInPixels :: model.y : modelYRange
```

> I do not want to use the `JFreeChart`. Is there any other way?

Yes, as @MadProgrammer [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234941/how-to-change-diagram-scale-in-java/35236166?noredirect=1#comment58187825_35234941), you can

- Scale the data to the enclosing container using the proportions shown above. The [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901472/230513) cited isolates the basic approach; [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) is a full featured example.
- Scale the rendered image to the enclosing container using a `BufferedImage`. This [example's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513) `ComponentHandler` draws into a `BufferedImage` that is sized to fill the enclosing `JPanel`. The `background` image is rendered in the implementation of `paintComponent()`. Resize the frame to see the effect.
- Scale the rendered image to the enclosing container using a transform applied to the graphics context. Typical examples are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014525/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594424/230513).

Comment: Thank you. However I do not want to use the JFreechat. Is there any other way ?

Comment: I've elaborated above.