# JLabel text Y paint coordinate

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

The default `JLabel` draws its text at the middle of its bounds. For example, if `height` of the label is 20, `font height` is 14, the `Y` coordinate would be `(20 - 14)/2 = 3`. Like this:

[image: Red line is the JLabel bounds]

What should I do if want to align the text to the `TOP` of the `JLabel` `bounds`? Like this:

[image: Red line is the JLabel bounds]

**UPD:**

```
public class LabelTest extends JFrame {

    public LabelTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        contentPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));

        final JLabel label1 = new JLabel("JLabel");
        label1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP); // by the answer of Kevin Workman, doesn't help
        label1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        label1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        contentPanel.add(label1);

        setContentPane(contentPanel);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LabelTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, the API is your best friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setVerticalAlignment(int)

Edit- Based on your updated SSCCE, the problem is that your BoxLayout is shrinking the JLabel as small as it will go, so the vertical text position doesn't really matter. Try using a BorderLayout to check that.

The problem is that the insets of the JLabel are adding a small space to the top and bottom of the JLabel, so your text looks centered even though it's at the top. Here's a fix for the insets problem: [How to change gap in swing label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157704/how-to-change-gap-in-swing-label)

Comment: Thanks, but no, it doesn't help.

Comment: I've written *label1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP)*, but I still see that JLabel is similar to first picture attached.

Comment: Then you need to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating exactly what you've done, because the setVerticalAlignment() method works perfectly for me.

Comment: `SSCCE` attached in **UPD** section

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

You should be `pack`ing the frame. If you so this, there *should* be no unused space in the label. If you want empty space, use an empty border

```
label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 5, 0));

                           top, left, bottom, right
```

Also, don't set sizes, Use Layout Mangers and let them do the sizing for you. Setting sizes will give you. Setting sizes will give you a rigid look that may look and perform differently on different platforms.  Layout Managers will allow your GUI to be more fluid and adaptable to different environments.

See [**Laying out Components Within a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more information on working with layouts

Also see [**Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

---

Comment: Thanks, it helps me. BTW, it is better to use `BorderFactory` instead of `EmptyBorder` creation by hand. IMHO ;)

Comment: What's the difference? It's just a convenience class but does the same thing, doesn't it?

Comment: It is. I mean the convenience.

Comment: *>if you want the label at the top*  ohhh.. I want the `text inside the label at the TOP`, **not the** `label at the top of parent`...

Comment: Your first answer without any editions was perfect =D

Comment: Was just trying to accomodate your edit... duly noted though, additions deleted :)