# How do you color certain cells?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm working on a school project. I am writing Sudoku. A Sudoku block consist of 9x9 blocks. Of those 9x9 blocks the Sudoku is divided into 3x3 blocks (9 of them).

How do I color those 3x3 blocks the same color to be able to see in what block your working in (i.e. background colors)?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4151403/230513).

Answer (score 1):

The cells in a `JTable` can be styled using a custom `TableCellRenderer`, which provides a *flyweight component* ( for example a `JLabel`) to render each cell. When the cell is editable, you also specify a custom `TableCellEditor`, which may or may not follow the same style as the renderer.

The **UI state** (such as the current cell you're working on, to color the group of cells) is best kept in a *presentation model* (can be a simple bean), which is accessible from your cell renderer and editor, to decide how to style the cell.