# Grid of textfields for Sudoku

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm new to programming so I've just recently learned about GUIs and am still in the learning process of how to make them. I'm making sudoku but I don't know how to make a 9x9 grid of textfields so I would like some assistance with creating that.

Comment: _I don't know how to make a 9x9 grid of textfields_ what exactly is the problem? Layout? Creation of fields? Looping? .. Show what you have done so far and where exactly you are stuck

Answer (score 2):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on How to Use [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for an example or arranging components in a grid.

I suggest you look at the table of contents for the tutorial to learn the basics of Swing programming.

Comment: More ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4151403/230513).