# How to set platfrom-idependent size for jLabel containing one digit?

Tags: java, swing

How to do it? I need to put a `JLabel` sized so as it would contain 1 digit with a default `Font`. Is there a way to do it in a platform-independent way?

Comment: What happened when you added one digit to the `JLabel`? How is it not sizing correctly (on which platform)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It should stay the same. On any platform. Is it possible?

Comment: Read up on [Physical and Logical Fonts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html). Specifically, the section on "Lucidia Fonts".

Comment: `It should stay the same. On any platform.` - you can't control that because you don't know what the default font is on every platform. You should just set the text and let the layout manager do its job. Or the other approach is to create an Icon of the character, then add the Icon to  the label. Now the Icon will be consistent on all platforms.

Comment: @camickr _you don't know what the default font is on every platform_ But the platform on which the applcaition is going to be run does. I thought it would be possible to defne it in apltform independent-way and swing can do this out-of-a-box.

Comment: It does do it in a platform independent way. You set the text and use a layout manager.

Comment: `label.setText("1")` then add it to container with an appropriate layout manager, maybe like `GridBagLayout`, see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4151403/230513) shows an approach for `JButton`.